# Sonar quality profile in command line cannot be replaced by a project profile

Tags: sonarqube

Having a look to our build logs, I can see this warning:

> build 31-Dec-2015 10:37:39    [WARN] [10:37:39.896] Ability to set quality profile from command line using 'sonar.profile' is deprecated and will be dropped in a future SonarQube version. Please configure quality profile used by your project on SonarQube server.

Even if I can easily understand why it could be deprecated, I have an issue with that. We have a single SonarQube installation for all our teams. Each team must be compliant with a given Quality Gate but can define its own profile, depending on the needs. We are working with git branches. We have "static" branches such as master and develop, but also feature and bugfix branches which are also scanned (to insure code quality before merge). Entries in sonar are created also from command line

```
Dsonar.project.branch=${bamboo.planRepository.branch}
```

Which helps us to get one sonar entry per development branch.

Issue: Each time we create a feature, not having the command line will force us to go to Sonar and manually change the profile.

Do you have any suggestions, ideas, which may help us ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with the potential deprecation of this feature.  We have too many projects to be managing this administratively in sonarqube.

The best approach for our site is to allow the teams to select an approved profile using  setting in the maven pom.xml.